# How to sum in sql with a DISTINCT clause

Tags: sql, sum, distinct, sql-server-2012

In the following example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b36f/17)

How should I proceed to obtain the cumulative price for each 'Phone' instead of obtaining the last value?

In the example given below, I would need the following table to be produced:

```
Phone   Price   Purchases
50       35         3
51       50         2
52       99         3
55       21         2
53       16         2
54       21         1
56       16         1
58       22         1
57       10         2
```

This is to be done in SQL-Server 2012

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
select c1.phone,
  c2.TotalPrice,
  c1.purchases
from supportContacts c1
inner join
(
  select 
    max(Fecha) maxFecha,
    sum(price) TotalPrice, 
    phone
  from supportContacts
  group by phone
) c2
  on c1.phone = c2.phone
  and c1.Fecha  = c2.maxFecha
order by c1.phone;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b36f/71).

The subquery gets the Total sum for each phone along with the the max fecha associated with the phone.  You then use this and join back to your table on both the `phone` and the `fecha` to get the result.

Comment: The SQLfiddle gives 2 purchases for 51, I make it 4 :)

Comment: @MrFuzzyButton The OP wants the purchase value that is from the last entry.

Comment: I see, that wasn't very clear originally :)  ... I've updated my answer, for what it's worth!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a SQL Server 2012 handy, but give this a shot:

```
  select     
    phone,     
    purchases,
    price, 
    sum(price) over (partition by phone order by phone, price) as running_sum_purchases
 FROM 
    supportContacts
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't produce the required output...:(

Comment: Does "cumulative price for each 'Phone'" mean "rolling sum" or "running sum" ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just...

```
SELECT Phone, Sum(Price), Count(Purchases)
FROM  supportContacts
GROUP BY Phone
ORDER BY 1
```

.. or have I missed something?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b36f/41

50      35      3
51  50  4
52  99  3
53  16  2
54  21  2
55  21  1
56  16  1
57  10  1
58  22  2

If you need more details per phone, you can add a subquery :

```
SELECT
  Phone,
  Sum(Price) as Total,
  Count(Purchases) as Purchase_Count,
  (SELECT TOP 1 Price
   FROM supportContacts sc2
   WHERE sc2.phone=sc1.phone
   ORDER BY fecha DESC
  ) as Most_Recent
FROM supportContacts sc1
GROUP BY Phone
ORDER BY Phone
```

or, for the actual requirement which I've finally worked out :)

```
SELECT
  Phone,
  Sum(Price) as Total,
  Count(Purchases) as Purchase_Count,
  (SELECT Purchases
   FROM supportContacts sc2
   WHERE sc2.phone=sc1.phone
   AND sc2.Fecha=
     (SELECT Max(Fecha)
      FROM supportContacts sc3
      WHERE sc3.phone=sc1.phone
     )
  ) as Last_Purchase
FROM supportContacts sc1
GROUP BY Phone
ORDER BY Phone
```

.. which is starting to get quite unwieldy, there's probably an optimisation possible, but I'm losing the will to play... LOL

But thanks for the cerebral exercise of trying to do it this way :)

**EDIT**
I would probably have done it like this, if it had been me...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b36f/98

```
With PhoneGroup as
( SELECT
    Phone,
    Sum(Price) as Total_Price,
    Max(Fecha) as Last_Fecha
  FROM supportContacts
  GROUP BY Phone
)
SELECT
  Phone, Total_Price,
 (SELECT Purchases
  FROM supportContacts sc2
  WHERE sc2.phone=PhoneGroup.phone
    AND sc2.Fecha=PhoneGroup.Last_Fecha
 ) as Last_Purchase
FROM PhoneGroup
ORDER BY Phone
```

Comment: [Please don't use `ORDER BY 1` - it's a bad habit that can lead to trouble](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal.aspx).

Comment: It's quite close, but how I would get the last value of 'Purchases' in this case. Note that I don't need the count of purchases but the last value that appears associated to each phone. 'Last' function is not working (is this a issue with SQL Fiddle?)

Comment: My final version ended up the same as bluefeet's, but written as a CTE instead :) ... Cheers